# move a row between tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to move a row from `posts` to `archive`.
Both tables have the same columns.

```
$st = $db->query("select * from posts where id = " . $id);
while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    $date = $row['date']; ...

$sql = "insert into archive (date,...) values (:adate,...)";

$st = $db->prepare($sql);

$st->execute(array(
    ":adate" => $date, ...

$st = $db->query("delete from posts where id = " . $id);
```

`id` column is auto-increment on both tables.

Is there any shorter way to do this, because there are 14 columns on each table?

Comment: Does PHP support batch inserts?

Comment: There is a `INSERT .... SELECT` statement so the database can do it in one go.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the columns are of the same types and in the same order, you can do `insert into archive select * from posts where id = :id`. However, this will insert into `archive` with the same id.

```
    MariaDB [temp]> select * from posts;
    +------+-------+-------+
    | id   | a     | b     |
    +------+-------+-------+
    |    2 | test3 | test4 |
    |    1 | test  | test2 |
    +------+-------+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [temp]> select * from archive;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [temp]> insert into archive select * from posts where id = 2;
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
    Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

    MariaDB [temp]> select * from archive;
    +------+-------+-------+
    | id   | a     | b     |
    +------+-------+-------+
    |    2 | test3 | test4 |
    +------+-------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)

    MariaDB [temp]>
```

If you want to let the id column auto-increment normally, you will have to select each column like `insert into archive (date,...) select (date,...) from posts where id = :id`

```
    MariaDB [temp]> select * from posts;
    +------+------+-------+
    | id   | a    | b     |
    +------+------+-------+
    |    1 | test | test2 |
    +------+------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [temp]> select * from archive;
    +----+-------+-------+
    | id | a     | b     |
    +----+-------+-------+
    |  2 | test3 | test4 |
    +----+-------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [temp]> insert into archive (a, b) select a, b from posts where id = 1;
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
    Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

    MariaDB [temp]> select * from archive;
    +----+-------+-------+
    | id | a     | b     |
    +----+-------+-------+
    |  2 | test3 | test4 |
    |  3 | test  | test2 |
    +----+-------+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [temp]>
```

Comment: can't believe there is no way like `move all except id from table to table`. Anyway, thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I suggest you to use the following approach:

```
$ids = array(3, 7, 15, 31, 45);
$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO Archive SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Posts WHERE `id` IN ('.$clause.');');
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $ids);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM Posts WHERE `id` IN ('.$clause.');');
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $ids);
$stmt->execute();
```

The `IN` statement lets you avoid using a single query for every ID while the `INSERT INTO` statement lets you avoid performing a selection for every insertion. Overall, the performance of your process should be improved.

On the top of that, I recommend you to perform all that within a `TRANSACTION`, so that your tables won't get messed up if one of the two queries fails or if your server encounters a problem.